# How to get selected rows using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

Please help me to get the results from the query given below using **Hibernate**. Please convert these SQL queries to Hibernate. Thank you.

```
select project_id, project_name from project

SELECT * FROM `developer` WHERE `scrum_master_id` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select project_id, project_name from project

FROM developer d where d.scrum_master_id is null
```

Use Your Mapped names (Class names and field names) in query instead of table names or column names, i have write same names for your understanding.

Comment: Using plain values to associate entities is not a good thing (`d.scrum_master_id`) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from Project

from Developer where scrumMaster.id is null
```

You need to have `Project`, `Developer`, `ScrumMaster` persistents and an an associaton from `Developer` to `ScrumMaster`.